# can i insert a php array into a single mysql record field?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

suppose we have a mysql table "table" with fields "user" "siblings" and we want to store this family info for every user.

is it possible to do this:

```
$user=35;
$sibs=array("george","christina");

mysql_query("insert into table (user,siblings) values ('$user','$sibs')");
```

so that field "siblings" contains an array?

Comment: Please search before posting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880276/php-mysql-array-insert-array-info-into-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use PHP's [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function for this. To reverse the process, use [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Snippit from PHP.net:

```
<?php
// $session_data contains a multi-dimensional array with session
// information for the current user.  We use serialize() to store
// it in a database at the end of the request.

$conn = odbc_connect("webdb", "php", "chicken");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn,
      "UPDATE sessions SET data = ? WHERE id = ?");
$sqldata = array (serialize($session_data), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) {
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn,
     "INSERT INTO sessions (id, data) VALUES(?, ?)");
    if (!odbc_execute($stmt, $sqldata)) {
        /* Something went wrong.. */
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i'll try this, i wasn't familiar with serialize to be honest

Answer (score 3):

To build on @David Houde's answer from the post he refered to also use compression to save space (if useful to you):

```
<?php
mySerialize( $obj ) {
   return base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($obj)));
}

myUnserialize( $txt ) {
   return unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($txt)));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use serialize https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

But it's really bad practice.

Comment: i usually prefer implode but in this occasion, which is much more complicated than the example i've given, won't work

Comment: Can you say why `serialize` is bad practice?

Comment: @pavium Because 1) if you need to store key-val pairs, then Mysql is not the best choice 2) if in future you'll want to select all items, who has one (or more) properties from list, then you'll be in a big trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use implode() to add a divider between values. For example, you can use the pipe "|"

e.g.

```
$user=35;
$sibs=array("george","christina");

$sibs1 = ''.implode('|',$sibs).'|';

mysql_query("insert into table (user,siblings) values ('$user','$sibs1')");
```

When extracting information from the database use `LIKE '%|$var|%'` in your query to extaract the exact value. e.g. |Christina|

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `serialize()` the array prior to inserting it, or `implode()` it with some kind of a separator of your choice for this, but I would recommend you just insert separate rows for each user->sibling relationship.

Comment: i thought about implode, and i usually use this. but in fact the example i've given here is much more complicated than the real problem i have to encounter. didn't know about serialize, i'll give it a shot

Comment: I'm sure you'd get a much better solution than if you just post the problem that you're trying to solve. :)